# Substring and adding leading zeros to a string value

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, substring

Hi all – I need some assistance with prefixing leading zeros into a string.

I have had a look around in the forum but did not quite find anything that suits my scenario.

The string in the column is in the following format: ‘INV-ACC-180 Some description etc’

The ‘INV-ACC-180’ bit is always the same format whilst the description can vary.

The challenge is the ‘180’. Its needs to be 4 leading zeros so it shows as 0180. i.e ‘INV-ACC-0180 Some description etc’

Some records may look like ‘INV-ACC-80 Some description etc’.  And in this case the new correct format should be ‘INV-ACC-0080 Some description etc’

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is the 180 stored as a separate value ?
In that case you create 0180 using:

```
RIGHT('0000' + mynum, 4)
```

if the complete string is the input:

```
‘INV-ACC-' + RIGHT('0000'+substring(myinput,9,charindex(' ',myinput)-9),4) +substring(myinput,charindex(' '),1000)
```

Comment: Thanks for this but it doesnt quite work :( the charindex is missing an parameter so I added "myinputstring" which then didnt return the desired results.

Comment: You're right, I've corrected the statement. The third parameter of substring is the length and not the end position so changed that too.

Comment: Hi - Yes! That worked. Had to amend the lenght to get the desired result but nonetheless, works perfectly :) Thankas heaps!